# Php form based authentication in combination with ldap authentication

Tags: php, apache, ldap

I working on a webpage and want to protect most of the page with a loginpage before entering the pages. I was thinking about directory access protection.
I have setup two test directory with the following settings in apache:

```
<Location /test>
# Using this to bind
AuthLDAPBindDN "##########"
AuthLDAPBindPassword "##########"
# search user
AuthLDAPURL "##########?sAMAccountName?sub?     (objectClass=*)"
AuthType basic
AuthName "USE YOUR WINDOWS ACCOUNT"
AuthBasicProvider ldap
# Important, otherwise "(9)Bad file descriptor: Could not open password file: (null)"
AuthUserFile /dev/null
Require ldap-group ###########
#Require valid-user
</Location>


<Location /test2>
# Using this to bind
AuthLDAPBindDN "##########"
AuthLDAPBindPassword "###########"
# search user
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://##########?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
AuthType form
AuthName "USE YOUR WINDOWS ACCOUNT"
AuthFormProvider ldap
AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation "../test_ldap.php"
# Important, otherwise "(9)Bad file descriptor: Could not open password file: (null)"
AuthUserFile /dev/null
Require ###################
#Require valid-user
</Location>
```

One has LDAP authentication, that one is working fine but gives an ugly Windows popup. I want to replace that to a form based page so I can customize the look and feel.

The other one is using formbased authentication. The redirect to the login form page is working fine but then im stuck. I have created a php page that validates to LDAP that is also working fine so that is my landing page but then still when I access my protected directory its not authenticated.

So I need a combination of both to get this working.
I have seen that the AuthFormProvider can be set to Ldap, and have done that but I don't get that to work.

I would be very gratefull if somebody could guide me in this project to the right direction.

Comment: Can Anybody help me out with this ?